# which web services stacks are supported on JBoss AS 5?

Tags: apache-axis, cxf, jboss5.x

I've been trying to find this info in JBoss docs/forums/WIKIs - but could not get a concise answer to this question:

Which web services stacks are supported (or you can make work on) in JBoss 5?

I have a huge legacy app using Axis 1 web services which is running fine on WLS9.2. Now I have to migrate it to JBoss 5 and I have to decide whether I can leave Axis1 web services as is (at least for the time being, to get the app working on JBoss at all), or if I have to upgrade web services to Axis 2 or CXF.

So, given the three options, Axis 1, Axis 2 and CXF - what does support for them look like on JBoss 5? Any gotchas, pain points, words of wisdom from experience? :)

Answer (score 0):

See [JBossWS User guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Jbossws-userguide) for details

Answer (score 0):

Axis1 works fine on 4.2.x. No idea about 5. Sorry i can't be more helpful than that!